# how can I set template0 for my new postgresql db on pgadmin

Tags: database, postgresql, templates, pgadmin

I want to create a db in postgre sql and I want to set its `template` property to `template0` in pgAdmin III, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on the databases and select `new Database...`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the [CREATE DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createdatabase.html) statements:

```
CREATE DATABASE your_database_name WITH TEMPLATE template0;
```